# What is the difference between Environment.Exit(0) and Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode)?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between `Environment.Exit(0);` and `Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);`?

I've used both, and they seem to do the same thing. So which one should I use?

Comment: Probably nothing unless you explicitly set it somewhere

Comment: Did you try to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-5.0#parameters) (and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exitcode?view=net-5.0))? Short answer, the only difference is if you care about setting the exit code for any app that called your executable.

Comment: Ok got it.... –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've used both, and they seem to do the same thing.

As others have already noted, that's because the default value for `ExitCode` is 0.

> So which one should I use?

Typically, if you call [`Exit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-5.0#parameters), you a) have a good reason for that and b) you want to terminate as soon as possible with **all the disadvantages** described in the remarks section.

Therefore you would

- never call `Environment.Exit(0);` and instead let the `void Main()` method run to its end in a normal way.
- never call `Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);` because that would imply that the reason for the termination was set a while back.
- call `Environment.Exit(ERRORCODE);`, likely with a meaningful constant instead of a magic number

So the real answer is: don't use it at all, if possible.

Instead you might want to try [`Window.Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.close?view=net-5.0) to close a single window or [`Application.Exit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=net-5.0), which closes all windows and gets you back to the `Main()` method and out of the `Application.Run()` method call.

If that's not sufficient to terminate your program and you still see it in Task Manager, it has a [foreground thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads) running, e.g. a thread that saves the users work. You don't want to terminate that, because it could result in a corrupted file.

There is a concept of a boolean `isRunning` or [`_shouldStop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) variable to terminate threads.

If you don't know why your application is not terminating, attach a debugger and have a look at the callstack of the remaining threads.

Comment: Well, I use `Environment.Exit(0);` and `Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);` In a winforms app because `Application.Exit();` keeps parts of the app running in the background.

Comment: `So the real answer is: don't use it at all, if possible.` So should I use `Application.Exit();` in a winforms app out of both of these?

Comment: I've extended my answer

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `Environment.ExitCode` is 0 so normally, there won't be a difference. But since `ExitCode` is an integer it can be set to any value e.g `Environment.ExitCode = 1`. If a system fails it can set ExitCode to 1 and when the environment exits on either `Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode)` or just end of the program it would have `ExitCode` 1 instead of 0. Anything other than 0 would indicate an error.

Comment: So does that mean doing `Environment.Exit(1);` do the same thing as ```Enviroment.ExitCode = 1;
Environment.Exit(Enviroment.ExitCode);```?

Answer (score 2):

**Environment.ExitCode** is a **int** static property which by default takes the value of **0**. This is because **int** is a **Value Type** and the default value is **0**.

So, if in your code you don't set the value of **Environment.ExitCode** other than **0** ,then they will be the same thing.